How do I type the extra symbols on European or Latin keyboard layout in Gnome
I recently switched from an English (US) layout that provides only two letter variants for each key. The one that is typed when the key is pressed alone, and the other when the key is pressed with Shift.

To a European layout (in this case it is Serbian (Latin)) with four letter variants.

How do I type the extra two letters?
Here is how the keyboard settings are presented in setxkbmap -print output
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+rs(latin):3+us:4+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+compose(ralt)"
        };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};


The extra keys can be typed with the Alt R or AltGr key. In my configuration in English (US) Alt R works as Compose key, but with the Serbian Latin keyboard it becomes the modifier to enable the third and fourth character on the keyboard.
For example, to type "€" I have to type Alt R+e.
